# Pandas forward fill with scalar multiple of last value

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict1 = {'A': [100,200, np.nan, 300, 500, np.nan, np.nan, 50], 
         'B': [0,1,np.nan,1,10, np.nan, np.nan, 5], 
         'C' : [100,200, np.nan, 300, 500, np.nan, np.nan, 200]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict1)
```

I wish to forward fill the data such that the `np.nan` values are a scalar multiple `s` of the last value. Say `s = 0.5`.

I tried `df1.fillna(0.5*df1)` but it didn't work

My expected outcome would be:

```
      A     B      C
0  100.0   0.0  100.0
1  200.0   1.0  200.0
2  100.0   0.5  100.0
3  300.0   1.0  300.0
4  500.0  10.0  500.0
5  250.0   5.0  250.0
6  250.0   5.0  250.0
7   50.0   5.0  200.0
```

Comment: Your `df1.fillna(0.5*df1)` is missing a `ffill` method see my solution below.  pandas will use data alignment to populate the appropriate NaN cells in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
df1.fillna(df1.ffill().mul(.5))
```

Output:

```
       A     B      C
0  100.0   0.0  100.0
1  200.0   1.0  200.0
2  100.0   0.5  100.0
3  300.0   1.0  300.0
4  500.0  10.0  500.0
5  250.0   5.0  250.0
6  250.0   5.0  250.0
7   50.0   5.0  200.0
```